# What's the difference between "judicial" and "juridical"?

Tags: synonyms

I have found the definitions below from Merriam-Webster (my bold) and, aside from the fact that judicial has a wider use (and definition) than juridical (most of which I cut from this excerpt). When using each word as per my highlighted definition, is there a technical difference in what is being referred to or are they synonyms?

> ju·rid·i·cal adj \ju̇-ˈri-di-kəl\
>
> Definition of JURIDICAL
>
> 1: **of or relating to the administration of justice** or the office of a judge
>
> 2: of or relating to law or jurisprudence : legal

> ju·di·cial adj \jü-ˈdi-shəl\
>
> Definition of JUDICIAL
>
> 1a : **of or relating to** a judgment, the function of judging, **the administration of justice**, or the judiciary (judicial processes)

Comment: Thanks for the acceptance, but in future you might consider leaving questions open for a day or two, in case somebody offers a better answer.

Comment: @Tim - very magnanimous of you. I've removed the tick for the time being. The specific text I had referred to Russia rather than Britain but I thought that your answer was very clearly explained

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Historically there was no difference, and I suspect that is still so in some parts of the world.  But in the British legal system at least there is a valuable difference, namely that *juridical* relates to the system of justice generally whereas *judicial* refers specifically to the acts of a judge.  So if a judge says "You will go to jail for contempt" that is a judicial order;  but there is a considerable amount of juridical paperwork to be completed.

You can, for example, buy books of precedents, and if they refer to court papers they are sometimes called *juridical styles*. But if a judge thinks the form is a bad one, there may be a footnote saying *Judicially disapproved.*

Comment: Historically there is a difference, one is based on juridicus which in latin is everything related to the law and rights, the other is based on judicarius/judicium which is the judgment itself. But everything else in this answer is spot on.

Comment: @ColinHebert: there is a difference between *historically* and *etymologically*.  You are largely right about the derivations (though both come ultimately from *judex*); but several 18th-century books use the two words interchangeably. I suspect this is because of the tendency, before the rule of law was formalized, to think that the law was what the king's judge said it was; "It has no kind of fault or flaw/ And I, my lords, embody the law".

Answer (score 4):

[dailywritingtips](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/juridical-and-juridicial/)

> The adjective juridical means “relating to the administration of the law.”
>
> The adjective judicial means “relating to courts of law or judges.”
>
> We can talk about the judicial system (the organization of courts and judges) or a judicial decision (one made by a judge).
>
> We can talk about a juridical interpretation of an action (strictly according to the law) or a juridical system (a body of laws by which a state or organization is governed).

That may outline the essential difference, for now.

Answer (score 2):

In the US, I would say that "judicial" relates to the courts of law or to the legal system.  And "juridical" I would not use myself.

Comment: Agreed - I'm sure "juridical" has some use in law circles, but in everyday parlance you'd get strange looks using it.